# hoc component in react native and redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

i want to show spinner when user requesting `Api` call
and i passed each component into higher order
component to check is requesting or not
if requesting show the spinner otherwise not

but here i getting error that says cannot call class as function

```
//-------------Hoc Component

HOC=component=>class extends React.component{

  render(){
    (return <component {...props} {...state}/>)}
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HOC)

//----------login component

export default HOC(connect(mapStateToProps,{actions})(Login))
```

Without HOC it is working fine but with HOC getting error. Please let me know the solution that how to connect two higher order component

Comment: your question is not readable. Please edit to make it readable. Check the preview before saving

Comment: Instead of this --> HOC(connect(mapStateToProps,{actions})(Login)) do this ---> connect(mapStateToProps,{actions}))(HOC((Login)))

Comment: not working yaar

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
const HOC = WrappedComponent => {
  class abc extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({ state });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreaters({..actions}, dispatch);
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(abc);
}

export default compose(
  HOC,
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Login);
```